# Why are some screen classes fully qualified in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

When viewing screen_view event details, some screen classes appear twice in both their fully-qualified and not fully-qualified forms.

For example:

```
                                %total    avg time
ViewControllerClass             9%       17s
ModuleName.ViewControllerClass  1%       30s
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: when was the first time you release the app? What version of the Firebase Analytics SDK that you first got? If you released with an old version of Analytics before the removal of the Swift class name, you probably still receive the full name of the screen classes as users might not update their app to the newer versions.

Comment: can you provide the first version of the SDK? It'd be better to debug for the team.

Comment: actually, I spoke too soon. This is an adequate explanation to the problem. The most recently created view controller is not appearing twice.